# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 1 Continuity Condition

Tags: calculus

The fundamental theorem of calculus part 1 states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then the function $F$ ($F$ is defined as $F(x)=\int_a^x f(x)dx$) is differentiable on $[a, b]$. Intuitively, I don't understand this. If $f$ was a step function (and thus discontinuous) over $[a, b]$, wouldn't $F$ still be a smooth function and thus differentiable?

Comment: The modulus is smooth on [-1,1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your step function $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(1,2]$, then you would have:

$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt=\int_0^x0\,dt=0 \hspace{1cm} \text{ if $x\leq 1$,}$$

$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt=\int_0^1f(t)\,dt+\int_ 1^xf(t)\,dt=\int_0^10\,dt+\int_ 1^x1\,dt=x-1 \hspace{0.5cm}\text{if $x>1$.}$$

But the function $F:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $F(x)=x-1$ for $x\in(1,2]$ is not smooth (since not differentiable at $1$).